# datetime.datetime.now returning "received a naive datetime while time zone support is active"

Tags: python, django, datetime, timezone

in my project i have multiple apps , and multiple models , in some models i define time = datetime.datetime.now() , however when i do .save() to save the object to the database i get the warning "received a naive datetime while time zone support is active" . I dont want this warning , i know that i can add zonal information (using timezone) to remove this warning however adding it manually everywhere throughout the project would be tedious. i also tried adding  `USE_TZ = False` to the settings file however i have models where i want the zonal information to be enabled. So basically i want my project to support both cases where we pass and dont pass zonal information, i dont want the warning to be displayed when saving an object and i dont want to add timezone manually

eg:

```
a = Apple.objects.create()
a.start = datetime.datetime.now()
a.save()
```

RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField Shift.expected_in_time received a naive datetime (2024-03-28 13:00:36) while time zone support is active.
I dont want this warning
`

```
a = Apple.objects.create()
aware_datetime = aware_datetime = timezone.make_aware(datetime.datetime.now(), timezone=timezone.get_current_timezone())
a.start = aware_datetime
a.save()
```

`
now no warning is seen , however changing it manually everywhere is time consuming , is there a faster way to do it

Comment: Some information about your language/platform would be useful.  I suspect you're asking about Python / Django?  If so, please update your tags accordingly.  Also, you should include code examples in your question so we can understand you better.  Thanks.

Comment: "_faster way to do it_" not really, you'd need to replace it everywhere anyway. You could try to use the find and replace functionality in whatever editor / IDE you use. Also rather than using `make_aware` on `datetime.datetime.now()` consider simply using `django.utils.timezone.now()`

Comment: i could do that but testing becomes an issue and doing it manually is always prone to error , moreover in some places we are using IST and in some UTC